Proof and Intuition behind the directional derivative of a scalar function f being $\nabla f(\textbf{a}) \cdot \textbf{v}$
Specifically why is it that the directional derivative of f at a in the direction v defined  by
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\textbf{a}+h\textbf{v}) -f(\textbf{a})}{h}$$
is equal to $$\nabla f(\textbf{a}) \cdot \textbf{v}$$
what is the proof of this and what's the intuition behind this?
The way I have thouhgt about it so far is that a the tangent plane of $f$ at $\textbf{a}$ will have a slope equal to the directional directive if you move in that direction. Which will be the dot product of the unit vector in that direction and the gradient but this still does not seem like a clear reason why the limit above would be equal to the gradient dotted with $\textbf{v}$.
I tried by constructing a tangent plane of $f(x,y)$ at some point and then intersecting it with the  vertical plane in the direction of $\textbf{v}$ and then try finding the slope of the line but I did not get very far with the math on this.
Apparently this is due to the chain rule for multivariable functions but I don't see the connection.
Edit: ok so I figured out that
$$D_{\textbf{v}}f(x_0,y_0) = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + sv_1,y_0+sv_2) - f(x_0,y_0)}{s}$$
which is supposed to be  $$\frac{d}{ds}[f((x(s),y(s))]|_{s=0}$$
but I don't understand how you get from the limit to this derivative.

Chain rule. $\phantom.$

Sometimes this is the definition of $\nabla f$. Sometimes this follows from the definition of $f$ being differentiable at $\mathbf{a}$. But if your definition of $\nabla f$ is the vector $\partial f/ \partial x_i$ then you may need such an assumption on $f$.

@KurtG. could you explain it explicitly I still don't understand it?

The proof requires the hypothesis of differentiability — you need to know that the tangent plane actually gives a good approximation to the graph of the function.   But the derivation you tried to give does work. Write the equation of the tangent plane $z-f(\mathbf a) = \nabla f(\mathbf a)\cdot (\mathbf x-\mathbf a)$ and plug in $\mathbf x = \mathbf a + \mathbf v$ (probably using a unit vector $\mathbf v$). The error between the tangent approximation and $f$ goes to $0$ faster than $|\mathbf x-\mathbf a|$, and so disappears in your limit.

Re your edit, that limit is the definition of the derivative.

Will this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367600 help you?

Or this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4053834/319307?

The connection to the chain rule is that you can consider the map
$$ \gamma : h \to f(a + hv)$$
as the composition of two functions $f(g(h))$ where $g(h) = a + hv.$
Assuming that the directional derivative of $f$ exists at $a$ then, by definition $\gamma'(0)$ is exactly that the directional derivative in the direction $v$.
If we assume that $f$ is differentiable at $g(0) = a$ and that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ then we can apply the chain rule for $f\circ g$ at $0$
$$ \gamma'(0) =  \frac{d f \circ g}{dh}_{\vert 0} = \nabla f(a) \cdot h$$
